# Slow running code due to a lot of objects hiding / unhiding

Tags: performance, excel, button, hide

I have a spreadsheet of about 20,000 rows.  This spreadsheet is a hierarchy that displays part lists for pieces of equipment.  I have created code that creates buttons (actually the shape rectangle) that allow the user to expand / contract these groups through hiding / unhiding rows.

I believe the code is running slow because there are several thousand buttons on the spreadsheet that I believe are refreshing each time rows are hidden.  When I click the button the code runs, the correct rows hide / unhide, then all the buttons dissapear for a few seconds then reapear. The disapearing occurs after the rows hide or unhide so the code has already finnished running.

Is there any way to stop Excel from refreshing every button? Is there a different issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could make use of the Pivot Table feature in Excel. I'm sure it's much faster than the macros/buttons the spreadsheet is using:

PIVOT TABLE OUTLINE
[image: Pivot Table Outline]

You just need to put in the effort of re-organizing your data into a decent format. Good Luck.

If you need an explanation of pivot tables you can just google "pivot table tutorial.
[http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pivot+table+tutorial%22](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22pivot%20table%20tutorial%22)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately a pivot table will not work in my scenario. The original list that the hierarchy is made from will be entered into a database program. This hierarchy is simply a visual representation for field review. The end user will have little to no knowledge of Excel.

Comment: I would think it would be much easier than populating your spreadsheet with buttons. You can create a pivot table using macros just as easily. Just put your standardaized data in excel, create the pivot table(you can record this to see how it is done), adjust is how you want it to be displayed, and then let them go wild clicking pluses and minuses. Doesn't really require any knowledge of excel. They just need to know how to use a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a workaround which I'll elaborate more when the code is handy,but is like so:

1. Have your button creating macro create hyperlinks in a cell instead with the text `+/-` and a tool tip of `>>expand/collapse<<`

   ```
   ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
       Anchor:=[A1], Address:="", _
       SubAddress:=[A1].Address, _
       ScreenTip:=">>expand/collapse<<", _
       TextToDisplay:="+/-"
   ```
2. In the `workseet_followhyperlink` event do a check to see if the tool tip is `>>expand/collapse<<` and if so follow you macro for sowing and hiding.

   ```
   if target.screentip = ">>expand/collapse<<" then 
       myShowHideMacro
   else
       'do other stuff
   end if
   ```